# HttpClient dosen't get data after update WP8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I have this code to get JSON data from an API for WP8:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(mainURL.ToString());
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var root = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<Rootobject>(res);
```

Everything works perfectly, but when I update data on the web API from the web site and try to retrieve data again using this code it gets the old data even though accessing the URL in a browser it gets the new data.

When I debug line by line, I see that the "response" object contains the old data.

The only way I have found to fix this is to rebuild the project in this way it works.

How can I properly get the updated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some caching involved. Tried adding some random string to the URL, like

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(mainURL.ToString()+"&random="+DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same kind of problem. I tried this this may be help you.

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(mainURL.ToString());
     request.Method = "GET or Post";
     request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallBack, request);


    void ResponseCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     {
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
                   using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                                {
                                    string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));
                                    DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Rootobject));
                                    Rootobject yourdata= dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as Rootobject;

                                }
                            }
     }
```